# How to get the results of other tables using includes or joins in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I want to query the results of private_classes. The scenario is:

```
class PrivateClass < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :private_school
  has_many :lesson_plans
end

class JoinedPrivateSchool < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :student
  belongs_to :private_school
end

class PrivateSchool < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :teacher
  has_many :private_classes
  has_many :joined_private_schools
end

class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :joined_private_schools
end
```

JoinPrivateSchool has the attribute `private_school_id`.

I am doing:

```
s = Student.find(9)

s.joined_private_schools
```

which results in:

```
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<JoinedPrivateSchool id: 8,
 user_id: 73, student_id: 9, private_school_id: 28, created_at: "2017-02-16 
12:38:37", updated_at: "2017-02-16 12:38:37">, #<JoinedPrivateSchool id: 9,
 user_id: 73, student_id: 9, private_school_id: 33, created_at: "2017-02-16 
12:42:01", updated_at: "2017-02-16 12:42:01">, #<JoinedPrivateSchool id: 12, 
user_id: 73, student_id: 9, private_school_id: 32, created_at: "2017-02-16 
13:19:02", updated_at: "2017-02-16 13:19:02">]>
```

If I do:

```
c = s.joined_private_schools.includes(private_school: :private_classes)
```

it results in:

```
JoinedPrivateSchool Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "joined_private_schools".* FROM 
"joined_private_schools" WHERE "joined_private_schools"."student_id" = $1 
 [["student_id", 9]]


PrivateSchool Load (0.9ms)  SELECT "private_schools".* FROM "private_schools" 
WHERE "private_schools"."id" IN (28, 33, 32)  ORDER BY 
"private_schools"."created_at" DESC


PrivateClass Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "private_classes".* FROM "private_classes" 
WHERE "private_classes"."private_school_id" IN (33, 32, 28)  ORDER BY 
"private_classes"."created_at" DESC


=> #<ActiveRecord::AssociationRelation [#<JoinedPrivateSchool id: 8, user_id: 
73, student_id: 9, private_school_id: 28, created_at: "2017-02-16 12:38:37",
 updated_at: "2017-02-16 12:38:37">, #<JoinedPrivateSchool id: 9, user_id: 73,
 student_id: 9, private_school_id: 33, created_at: "2017-02-16 12:42:01", 
updated_at: "2017-02-16 12:42:01">, #<JoinedPrivateSchool id: 12, user_id: 73,
 student_id: 9, private_school_id: 32, created_at: "2017-02-16 13:19:02", 
updated_at: "2017-02-16 13:19:02">]>
```

But that is still the wrong results.

I need to get the results of private_classes using one query so I can avoid multiple each loops.

Comment: I encourage you to take a look at this article (http://blog.bigbinary.com/2013/07/01/preload-vs-eager-load-vs-joins-vs-includes.html) to understand what `includes` (and `joins`, `eager_load` and `preload`) does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have `PrivateClass`, you're starting from the wrong point (`User`). You need to start from `PrivateClass` joining all the intermediary tables and using the user id as condition:

```rb
PrivateClass.joins(private_school: :user).where(user: {id: 9})

# or a little more performant (avoids one join)

PrivateClass.joins(:private_school).where(private_school: {user_id: 9})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `:through` on associations (at least in Rails 4.2)
I updated this, I first missed that you wanted private_classes

```
class JoinedPrivateSchool < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :student
  belongs_to :private_school
  has_many :private_classes, through: :private_schools
end

class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :joined_private_schools
  has_many :private_classes, through: :joined_private_schools
end

s = Student.find(9)
s.private_classes
```